# Enabling Redis API in Scylla DB

Tags: redis, scylla

This is my first time asking here.

Can anyone help me how to enable the Redis API in ScyllaDB?

I can't find anything about enabling the Redis API.

Also where/how should I set the `redis_port` is it in the `scylla.yaml`?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 5):

Add

```
redis_port: 6379
```

somewhere in scylla.yaml

more here
http://scylla.docs.scylladb.com/master/design-notes/protocols.html#redis-client-protocol

The config option code:
https://github.com/scylladb/scylla/blob/master/db/config.cc#L789

Adding info on how to use Redis API with Scylla Docker:

- run Scylla Docker with mapped Redis port

  docker run -p 6379:6379 --name some-scylla -d scylladb/scylla --smp 1 --memory 750M --overprovisioned 1
- update the scylla.yaml

  docker exec -it some-scylla bash

  vi /etc/scylla/scylla.yaml (add redis_port: 6379)

  supervisorctl restart scylla
- from the host server you can now use

  redis-cli
  127.0.0.1:6379> ping
  PONG

Comment: See also http://scylla.docs.scylladb.com/master/design-notes/redis.html

Note that, last I heard, the Redis API was considered experimental. So make sure to test.

Comment: Hi @TzachLivytan thank you for answering. I already check that part in the documentation. Before asking the question I already tried to set the `redis_port` in the `scylla.yaml` but I can't check if the Redis API is enabled. Also I am using Docker for my Scylla and for Redis server I am using my PC is that okay or not?

Comment: Added some info on how to use Redis API with Scylla on Docker

Comment: Hi @TzachLivyatan I tried your instruction on how to use it but I ran to a problem. When I am restarting `scylla` it gives me:
```
scylla: ERROR (not running)
scylla: ERROR (spawn error)
```
Also after using the restart command I also tried to open the `redis-cli` and try pinging but nothing happens :(
`Error: Server closed the connection`

. But thank you for your efforts and answering my questions :)

Comment: Look like toy hit a another issue, which I can not reproduce. Please open a Scylla issue and include all logs (for the restart issue). https://github.com/scylladb/scylla/issues

Comment: I think this issue is related to this one https://github.com/scylladb/scylla/issues/4704